# An inequality problem of product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, inequality, random-matrices, concentration-of-measure

Let $A,B \in \mathbb{R^{n\times n}_{\geq 0}}$ be random matrices where A is symmetric and B is both symmetric and PSD.

Suppose $\|A-\mathbb{E}A\|_{\text{op}}\leq \epsilon_1$ and 
$\|B-\mathbb{E}B\|_{\text{op}}\leq \epsilon_2$ both with high probability. Is this possible to prove a concentration as follows:

$\| (B+\lambda I)^{1/2} A (B+\lambda I)^{1/2} - \mathbb{E}[(B+\lambda I)^{1/2}] \mathbb{E}[A] \mathbb{E}[(B+\lambda I)^{1/2}]\|_{\text{op}}\leq \epsilon_3$  with high probability?

,where $\lambda \geq 0$ is a scalar and $I$ is the identity matrix.

(I tried to add and subtract $(B+\lambda I)^{1/2} \mathbb{E}[A] (B+\lambda I)^{1/2}$ and use triangle inequality but got stuck to prove the concentration of the second term.)

Comment: You have requested that this question be moved to MathOverflow. However, it is not possible to migrate questions that are over 3 months old. If you are inclined to ask it there, you should just go ahead and ask. (If you choose to do so, you may benefit from improving some of the formatting, and either delete this question or make links between the two to prevent duplication of effort).